# How to prevent user to download audio in react js? Like spotify website

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spotify

Im trying to create a streaming podcast website. But I want to prevent user to download the audio file. Like spotify does. How spotify mask the audio file?

Comment: They don't, not sure what you mean there? If you're referencing their Account APIs that's through authentication and checking of your membership but nothing stops a user from hitting record at full bitrate with OPUS.

Answer (score 0):

Spotify and many other streaming services don't make the source audio file accessible on client side, they split it into chunks that are transferred from their backend to your browser when hitting the play button.

You can refer to this documentation about streams, it is not only applicable to audio but for files in general: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API/Using_readable_streams

To play the audio in the browser you need to transfer the received data stream into an audio player (e.g. this one https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-streaming-audio-player)